# Using Beautiful Soup to get data from non-class section

Tags: python, parsing, python-2.7, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I am still very novice and learning python and beautiful soup.  I have gotten hung up on how to get text from a non-class piece of HTML.

This is the snippet of HTML I'm working with:

```
<section class="userbody">
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    <figure class="iw">
        <div id="ci">
            <img id="iwi" title="image 2" alt="" src="http://images.craigslist.org/00C0C_daJm4U9yU5B_600x450.jpg" style="min-width: inherit; min-height: 450px;"></img>
        </div>
        <div id="thumbs"></div>
    </figure>
    <div class="mapAndAttrs">
        <div class="mapbox">
            <div id="map" class="leaflet-container leaflet-fade-anim" data-longitude="-84.072447" data-latitude="33.908534" tabindex="0">
                <div class="leaflet-map-pane" style="transform: translate(0px, 0px);"></div>
                <div class="leaflet-control-container">
                    <div class="leaflet-top leaflet-left"></div>
                    <div class="leaflet-top leaflet-right"></div>
                    <div class="leaflet-bottom leaflet-left"></div>
                    <div class="leaflet-bottom leaflet-right">
                        <div class="leaflet-control-attribution leaflet-control"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mapaddress">

                Some Address

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="attributes"></div>
    </div>
    <section id="postingbody">
            some posting info
            <br></br>
             more posting info
             <br></br>
    </section>
    <section class="cltags"></section>
    <div class="postinginfos"></div>
</section>
```

I have been able to pull the address information:

```
     for address in soup.findAll("div", { "class" : "mapaddress" }):
       addressText = ''.join(address.findAll(text=True))
```

It appears findAll() doesn't work for tags that have don't have a class as I tried doing in

```
     for post in soup.findall("section", { "id" : "postingbody" }):
       postText = ''.join(post.findAll(text=True))
```

How would grab the text in section id="postingbody"?

Comment: Thanks guys.  This community is awesome!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can do the following, taking into consideration that `s` is the html string:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
print soup.find(attrs={'id' : 'postingbody'})
```

Output:

```
<section id="postingbody">
            some posting info
            <br/>
             more posting info
             <br/>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Games Brainiac's answer: To get the text just put .text behind it.

So:

```
print soup.find(attrs={'id' : 'postingbody'}).text
```

Comment: Thanks @SergioP. You knew where I was going :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using BeautifulSoup4, you do it like this:

```
element = soup.find(id="postingbody")
```