# What's the better way to scrape Craigslist location or city with Beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, craigslist

I'm really new on Python and I tried since yesterday to **scrape** location (city or googlemap information) of craigslist posts using Beautifulsoup.

I tried a way that I find on the site :
[Using Beautiful Soup to get data from non-class section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21203677/using-beautiful-soup-to-get-data-from-non-class-section)

but when I use :

```
for url in (url_list):

    page2 = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page2.content, 'html.parser')
    for address in soup.findAll("div", {"class": "mapaddress"}):
            addressText = ''.join(address.findAll(text=True))

    location.append(addressText)
```

I have `NameError: name 'addressText' is not defined` in the last line and I can't understand why.

If someone can help or offer an other solution I'd really appreciate,

Many thanks,

Comment: Indent the line `location.append(addressText)` and remove the blank line before it. Python is based on indentation. Without indentation, the line `location.append(addressText)` is out of the for loop, and cannot find the `addressText` variable, which is defined inside the for loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works but I have only some addresses, how can I hav all the cities or all the googlemaps href ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include enough code to allow us to run it. We would then be able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: fyi it's __scrape__ (and __scraper__, __scraped__, __scraping__) not scrap

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you didn't indent the code correctly. Try modifying it to

```
for address in soup.findAll("div", {"class": "mapaddress"}):
        addressText = ''.join(address.findAll(text=True))  
        location.append(addressText)
```